# The role of mass in the tablecloth trick

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, conservation-laws, friction

Apologies if this has already been answered, but I have a question about the role of mass in the classic tablecloth trick, where the demonstrator pulls the tablecloth out from underneath a set of dishes. This trick is more easily executed if the dishes have a greater mass, which is often used to demonstrate inertia in high school physics classes. My question is this: If the force accelerating the dishes is the force of friction between the dishes and the rapidly pulled tablecloth, how is it that mass ends up playing a role in this trick? The frictional force is proportional to the normal force, which is also proportional to mass.

\begin{align}
F_\text{friction} & = µF_\text{normal} \\
F_\text{normal} & = -mg \\
F & = ma \\
\text{Therefore }\quad  ma & =-µmg.
\end{align}

If the acceleration is inversely proportional to mass, and the accelerating force is proportional to mass, then the tablecloth trick should be independent of mass, correct?

I understand that the velocity of the tablecloth is important to the success of the trick because of the impulse time, but it seems to me that the mass of the dishes *does* make a difference. Is this real?

Comment: Does everything on the table have the same mass?  Is there a difference in how a (heavy) plate and a (light) desert spoon behaves?

Answer (score 1):

At first approximation, the mass cancels out.  This is because the force to accellerate a object to a specific speed is inversely proportional to mass, but the friction force is proportional to weight, which in steady gravity is proportional to mass.

Comment: And probably the first place this begins to fail is for objects of low mass and low density, e.g. a paper napkin.

Comment: @Carl: Yes, and that's because the classical ridgid body *friction is proportional to perpendicular force* rule fails.  With a napkin on a tablecloth, you have deformable rough surfaces at the macro level, which is nothing like rigid body friction.  Dishes and silverware on a reasonably smooth table cloth approximate to rigid body friction well enough for practical purposes.

Comment: I noticed this effect even with a rigid but low mass plastic plate- when I added mass (such as a few apples), the trick was easier to execute. Is this merely because our equation for frictional force is an oversimplification of the way frictional force actually works?

Comment: @bhaus: I expect with the lightweight plastic plate that air motion affects were significant.  With more weight, boundary layer air affects will matter less.